# How to call service bus azure in transactionscope

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

When I call MassTransit.Publish on service bus azure, I have an exception because the call is in TransactionScope.

```
The feature 'Transaction' is not supported with the current configuration
```

How send message on the bus with no transaction mode, in the transactionscope ?
I don't want transaction for bus but only for the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the in-memory outbox to perform the send after the transaction is completed.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "my-queue", e =>
{
    e.UseInMemoryOutbox();
    e.Consumer<MyConsumer>(...);
});
```

With configuration, order matters, so if you're using a Retry or other middleware component it should come before the in-memory outbox in the configuration. Your consumers should be after all middleware components.